# Este script shell es seguro?

Tags: shell

Encontré este repositorio de github para configurar diversas cosas en un servidor Linux, pero no sé si al instalar dicho script pueda de alguna forma infectar mi servidor.

Por lo que pude revisar leyendo el script, aparentemente no hay nada raro. Y aunque lo probaré en un servidor de testeo, quisiera estar seguro.

[Link en Github](https://github.com/AAAAAEXQOSyIpN2JZ0ehUQ/ADM-ULTIMATE-NEW-FREE)

Comment: Pues el shell que instala no parece tener nada raro, pero estar usando un poco de recursos que están en dropbox y demás, puede ser que soy muy viejo pero yo no lo haría.

Comment: @Alfabravo vale amigo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo básico es que en tu prueba uses wireshark o similar y revises todas las conexiones salientes, pa estar seguro que no comienzan a salir peticiones inesperadas.